# Minimum of polynom-function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

is there a possibility to find/calculate the minimum of the following functions without using a graphical calculator?:

1. $x^{-2} + x^{-1} + x + 1$
2. $x^{-0.5} + x + x^{0.5} + 1$

Comment: They are not polynomials. Can you calculate derivatives?

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm not familiar with the term "polynomial", but anyways, I tried to calculate the zero of the first derivative but I got no result either.
I have no approach to solve -2x^-3-x^-2+1 = 0 or -0.5x^-1.5+0.5x^-0.5+1 = 0

Comment: Yes I know: they are nasty equations. But with Newton method you can get a nice approximation in minutes. Obviously you have always Wolfram Alpha, but doing it by hand is a kind of satisfaction... But I need more space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving $x^3-x-2=0$ with Newton method

First we need an interval where the root can be

I made a table

$
\begin{array}{r|r}
  x & p(x)\\
\hline
 -2 & -8 \\
 -1 & -2 \\
 0 & -2 \\
 1 & -2 \\
 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
$

The solution is in $[1,2]$

Let's guess $x_0=1.5$

Then iteratively we define for $n>0$

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{p(x_n)}{p'(x_n)}$

Where $p(x)=x^3-x-2$ and $p'(x)=3x^2-1$

We get the following table

$
\begin{array}{r|r}
 n & x_n\\
\hline
 0 & 1.5 \\
 1 & 1.52174 \\
 2 & 1.52138 \\
 3 & 1.52138 \\
\end{array}
$

So the solution is $x\approx 1.52138$

You can try and find the solution to the second

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much!
But I still have one little question.
You used x^3−x−2=0 in your answer, whereas my function was  -2x^-3-x^-2+1 = 0. The result is indeed the same. Am I missing something and it is simplified or something like that?

Comment: @adriankroeger $$ -2x^{-3}-x^{-2}+1 =\frac{x^3-x-2}{x^3}$$

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
I used this approach with the other function and the result looks pretty good. I really have to thank you, you saved my day. Grazie mille

Answer (score 0):

First use some substitutions:

1. For the first function, $z=x^{-1}$.
2. For the second one, $z=x^{0.5}$ (so $x^{-0.5} = z^{-1}$)

Then you may use derivatives.